# Any good papers or literature about analysis of argumentation contexts?

Tags: argumentation, subjectivity, objectivity

Any good papers or literature about analysis of argumentation contexts?

By argumentation contexts I mean the context in which some discourse is written in, like what things does it claim about, is it time-dependent/independent, the relationship between subjective and objective (and the "values" between as well), and so on.

Comment: A good start is "A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations" by Kate L. Turabian.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

Peter Unger, 'Contextual Analysis in Ethics',  Philosophy and Phenomenological Research, Vol. 55, No. 1 (Mar., 1995), pp. 1-26.

William Rehg, 'Rhetoric, Cogency, and the Radically Social Character of Persuasion: Habermas's Argumentation Theory Revisited', Philosophy & Rhetoric, Vol. 46, No. 4 (2013), pp. 465-492.

Or probably more accessible :

D.N. Walton, Informal Logic: A Handbook for Critical Argumentation, SBN 10: 0521379253 / ISBN 13: 9780521379250
Published by Cambridge University Press.

Rybacki, Kathryn C., Rybacki, Donald J., Advocacy and Opposition: An Introduction to Argumentation, ISBN 10: 0130161306 / ISBN 13: 9780130161307.

Glen Earl Mills, Reason in controversy;: An introduction to general argumentation.

Richard E Crable, Argumentation as communication: Reasoning with receivers, ISBN 10: 0675086094 / ISBN 13: 9780675086097
Published by Merrill.

Philippe Besnard, Elements of Argumentation, ISBN 10: 0262026430 / ISBN 13: 9780262026437
Published by MIT Press, 2008.